# Which Context to use with MediaPlayer.create() in android?

Tags: android, performance, forceclose

Which context i should use with `MediaPlayer.create()` ?

I am using `Activity.this` with all my `MediaPlayer` objects. But i think it is giving me null pointer exception.

*Can context be a reason for force close in android or anything else ?*

Here "`com.bhavin.panara.kbc`" is package name.
And 108th line is `mediaplayer.start()`.

Here is code:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .
    .
    .
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayScreen.this, R.raw.sound);
    .
    .
    mp.start(); // 108th line.

    }
```

Here is my log cat report.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bhavin.panara.kbc/com.bhavin.panara.kbc.PlayScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1174)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4506)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bhavin.panara.kbc.PlayScreen.onCreate(PlayScreen.java:108)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1963)
... 11 more
```

Comment: post how you initialize your media player object

Comment: see line 108 of `PlayScreen.java`

Comment: MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ActivityName.this , R.raw.music);    
mp.start();   //Line 108

Comment: like @MrSuS says your problem is not Mediaplayer but load sorces. You didn't load PlayScreen. Since you didn't post all your code no one can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
  MediaPlayer media=new MediaPlayer();
  media.setDataSource(songname);
  media.prepare();
  media.start();
```

Comment: when i am using create method than no need to prepare it & start it.

Answer (score 0):

no it says a null pointer exception so may be it does get the said path of the file.
If you want to use the media player one method of it is:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);



player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG, "play Completed ...Starting Again ");
                player.start();
            }
        });

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(TAG, "preparation Completed ...playing ");
            player.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set the layout of the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs);

    //initialize views
    initializeViews();
}

public void initializeViews(){
    songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
    songName.setText("khmosia.mp3");
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.khmosia));
    mediaPlayer.start();
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);

    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
    seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
    seekbar.setClickable(false);
    Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            mediaPlayer.pause();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Welcome @Yogesh, Could you explain a bit more what you are doing with your code?